# Running applicatiom from eclipse causing phone restart

Tags: java, android, eclipse

im using eclipse to develop android app.

Im debugging my app on real device, htc desire hd.

When i start my app from eclipse its allways restart my phone.

This behavior wasnt allways like this and suddenly happaned.

I tried 3 different ROMs all 4.2.2 and its happing in all of them.

In my log cat i dont see any errors except this in my console:

```
[2013-09-05 21:25:33 - WorkoutLog2] Failed to install WorkoutLog2.apk on device 'HT0BRRX047774!
[2013-09-05 21:25:33 - WorkoutLog2] (null)
[2013-09-05 21:25:33 - WorkoutLog2] Launch failed on device: HT0BRRX047774
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: lol... share the code so we can reboot device without special permissions ;)

Comment: reboot doesn't always need special permission depending on the device (and ROM).

Comment: Usually, permission REBOOT is only available to apps signed by the key that signed the hardware, ie system apps. You can use this on a rooted device...